# Dynamic User Interface in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xml, user-interface, dynamic

Im struggling with a thought here. Let's say a user has his own CMS where he can fill the content for our app. One of his options is to create a view by uploading images and typing text. Well keep it very simple and imagine he only uploads a image (320 x 20) and some text. So an image on top and some textlines below.

What would be the best way to let my app know of this layout and download the contents? I was thinking of a downloadable XML file which defines the layout but don't really know how to implement this or if its even the best way.

Oh and the content and layout must be downloadable for offline use too.

Another option what I was thinking of is showing the layout in a webview but I can't figure out how to download the mobile website for offline use.

A push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We use a custom XML and it is working good. All texts inside 'label tags' are in XHTML

remember to:

- be specific when defining the xml to save some effort
- **write a limiting XSD! So nothing 'surprising' creeps into the xml**
- remember not include everything in ONE xml file as that would get rather large rather quickly. Choose a scheme for portioning the XML

Comment: So the basically you download the xml file and use that to create the user interface?

Comment: yes that what we do. there is no standard IF you want to have it at least in large part native

Comment: IF you don't care, use HTML+CSS

Comment: HTML+CSS was my second option but it should also be accessible offline.

Comment: you can download HTML and CSS just fine as well

Comment: Could you give me an example of that on the web? I can't figure out how to download a whole website with images and css to show in a webview